# Eigenvalue problem with matrices as matrix entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

### Notation

If $A$ is a matrix with dimensions  $(n,k)$ it is represented by $\hat A_{n,k}$

### Background

Consider the following matrix equations:

$$ a \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} + \hat b_{1 \times 2} \hat \kappa'_{2 \times 2} + e \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} = \lambda \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2}$$

$$ \hat b'_{2 \times 1} \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} + \hat c_{2 \times 2}  \hat \kappa'_{2 \times 2}  + \hat d_{2 \times 1} \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} = \lambda \kappa'_{2 \times 2}$$

$$ e' \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} + \hat d'_{1 \times 2} \kappa'_{2 \times 2} + f \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} = \lambda \kappa''_{1 \times 2}   $$

The above can be neatly written as:
$$
\begin{equation}
    \lambda
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa'_{2 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & \hat b_{1 \times 2} & e \\
   \hat b'_{2 \times 1} & \hat c_{2 \times 2} & \hat d_{2 \times 1} \\
     e' &  \hat d'_{1 \times 2} & f  \\  \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa'_{2 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\implies 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat 0_{1 \times 2} \\
    \hat 0_{2 \times 2} \\
    \hat 0_{1 \times 2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a -  \lambda & \hat b_{1 \times 2} & e \\
   \hat b'_{2 \times 1} & \hat c_{2 \times 2} -  \lambda . \hat I_{2 \times 2}  & \hat d_{2 \times 1} \\
     e' &  \hat d'_{1 \times 2} & f - \lambda  \\  \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat \kappa_{1 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa'_{2 \times 2} \\
    \hat \kappa''_{1 \times 2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

where $\hat I$ is the identity matrix

### Question

Is there any way one can define the determinant of such a matrix and find $\lambda$?